# Quiver with fear or in fear (preposition)

Tags: prepositions

The question is about prepostion

> The lightning stikes make townspeople **quiver in fear**.

Vs.

> The lightning stikes make townspeople **quiver with fear**.

The *first sentence* is taken from an online game, which I think the aforementioned "dependent preposition" is used by a native Englishman. Moreover, I believe this is **wrong**, and the *second sentence* (from my research) is more correct.

Is there by any chance **"quiver in fear”** (as set phrase) can be used? Or should it only be "**quiver with fear**"?

Comment: Your research is wrong, not the game. I wonder how you arrived at that conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are perfectly acceptable: "quiver with fear" is more common, but "quiver in fear" is somewhat more stylish. Here is an [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quiver+with+fear%2Cquiver+in+fear&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&) showing that there is not much difference between them in current usage.

Comment: +1  And yet **quiver in delight** is odd whereas **quiver with delight** is well attested. I wonder why we're **in** fear but not **in** delight.

Comment: The same goes for [other synonyms of _quiver_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trembled+with+fear%2C+trembled+in+fear%2C+shook+in+fear%2C+shook+with+fear&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) as well. This is one of those cases where there is no single “correct” preposition, but either one can be used. (Although, interestingly enough, this doesn’t hold true for [every single verb](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=filled+with+fear%2Cfilled+in+fear&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).)